# Excel VBA - Calculation is returning sum for Last Row instead of First Row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to set up a calculation that sums all of the values between "M" and "X" in each row.  However, when I run the code, it only gives me the sum for the last row in the worksheet, when it should be returning the sum for the 5th row in the worksheet.

The particular block I'm having problems with writing correctly is:

```
For i = 5 To LastRow
  If Not IsEmpty(.Range(.Cells(i, 13), .Cells(i, 24))) Then
Orig2016Total = .Range("M" & i).Value + .Range("N" & i).Value + .Range("O" & i).Value + .Range("P" & i).Value _
+ .Range("Q" & i).Value + .Range("R" & i).Value + .Range("S" & i).Value + .Range("T" & i).Value _
+ .Range("U" & i).Value + .Range("V" & i).Value + .Range("W" & i).Value + .Range("X" & i).Value
  End If
Next I
```

The line `.Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total`, which is bolded in the code block below, should be returning 780,000 for the 5th row sum, but instead it returns the last row's sum of 1,144,669.

Could someone please help me figure out why I'm getting the sum for the last row when it should be displaying the sum for the 5th row?  Thanks!!

The entire code is:

```
    Function ReduceCost_Percentage()

    With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim TodayDate As Date
    TodayDate = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")

    Dim Orig2016Total As Long
    Dim MonthsWithValues As Long


   For i = 5 To LastRow
      If Not IsEmpty(.Range(.Cells(i, 13), .Cells(i, 24))) Then
        Orig2016Total = .Range("M" & i).Value + .Range("N" & i).Value + .Range("O" & i).Value + .Range("P" & i).Value _
        + .Range("Q" & i).Value + .Range("R" & i).Value + .Range("S" & i).Value + .Range("T" & i).Value _
        + .Range("U" & i).Value + .Range("V" & i).Value + .Range("W" & i).Value + .Range("X" & i).Value
     End If
    Next i


    For i = 5 To LastRow
     If .Range("D" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
     And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) _
     And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
     And ((TodayDate >= Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2015#) Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2015#) Then
      .Range("M" & i).Value = ((.Range("M" & i).Value - Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) - ((.Range("M" & i).Value - Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) * (.Range("D" & i).Value * 0.01))) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    ElseIf .Range("D" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) _
    And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(.Range("M" & i).Value) _
    And (IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > TodayDate Or Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #12/31/2015#) Then
     .Range("M" & i).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value - (.Range("M" & i).Value * (.Range("D" & i).Value * 0.01))
    End If
   Next I

    'The code continues the same for columns "N" through "X" then it picks up again as:

    For i = 5 To LastRow

    .Range("Y" & i).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Range(Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 24)).Address(False, False) & ")"

    MonthsWithValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range(.Cells(i, 13), .Cells(i, 24)), "<>0", Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet").Range(.Cells(i, 13), .Cells(i, 24)), "<>""")

     If .Range("D" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
       If .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
       And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #11/30/2016# Then
        ***.Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total***
      ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
      And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #11/30/2016# Then
       .Range("Z" & i).Value = (Orig2016Total - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues
      ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) Then
       .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total / MonthsWithValues
      ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value = Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
      And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) Then
       .Range("Z" & i).Value = ((Orig2016Total - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
     ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
     And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) Then
       .Range("Z" & i).Value = (Orig2016Total - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues
     ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) Then
      .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total / MonthsWithValues
     End If
   End If
  Next i


   End With
   End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

While you loop over rows 5...LastRow in the first loop calculating the sum of the cells before changing their contents, you save each rowsum in the same scalar variable which can only hold one value. It gets overwritten in each iteration.

Instead, create `Orig2016Total` as an array of size `LastRow` so that you can put each rowsum for row `i` into `Orig2016Total(i)`. Then use the i-th array element in the following loops.

Comment: Thank you @user1016274!  I'm unsure of exactly how to write what you mentioned above.  Would you mind writing some code as an example of how I should write mine?   Thanks!!

Comment: Got it!  Just changed it to: `Dim Orig2016Total(68) As Long` and then         `For i = 5 To LastRow
                 If Not IsEmpty(.Range(.Cells(i, 13), .Cells(i, 24))) Then
                 Orig2016Total(i) = .Range("M" & i).Value + .Range("N" & i).Value + .Range("O" & i).Value + .Range("P" & i).Value _
+ .Range("Q" & i).Value + .Range("R" & i).Value + .Range("S" & i).Value + .Range("T" & i).Value _
+ .Range("U" & i).Value + .Range("V" & i).Value + .Range("W" & i).Value + .Range("X" & i).Value
  End If
Next I`

Comment: Great! You could substitute `68` to `LastRow` to make it universal. I wonder why you don't sum over `Range(Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 24))` instead of enumerating all single ranges.

Comment: I tried using `LastRow` like you mentioned, but it wouldn't work. What do you mean by "sum over `Range (Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 24))`"?

Comment: I think this leads too far. The code is working as it is, good. Didn't mean to bother you. There's always "neater" coding but that's not what it's about.